# Downloading Mac OS X to a PC

Tags: macos

Is it possible to download Mac OS X to a PC? Some people have told me that it is possible but I've done some research and I haven't found anything that really convinces me the real Mac OS is somewhere on the internet. I don't want to download a virus or something that is not actually Mac OS (but a "knockoff").

Is there any, 100%, Mac OS that can be downloaded to a PC? And if so, what is the link?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't download OS X installer from Internet, it is available only via Mac App Store.

If your want to build a PC able to run Mac OS X, this project is called [OSx86 or also known as Hackintosh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSx86).

There are a lot of guides and hardware compatibility lists on [tonymacx86 website](http://www.tonymacx86.com).
For example, if you want to install Mac OS X Yosemite on an Intel based PC you can follow [this instructions](http://www.tonymacx86.com/yosemite-desktop-guides/143976-unibeast-install-os-x-yosemite-any-supported-intel-based-pc.html#download_yosemite). As you can see, you have to previously download the Mac OS X image from the App Store to build a bootable USB drive.